# IdentityServer offset in identity claim

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

Given

Identity Server allowing RessourceOwner and Hybrid flow. 
The Hybrid flow is integrated in a website and the RessourceOwner Flow is used by an api.

When I sign in with **hybrid flow** I can see that there is a **subject claim**, containing the subject / id data.

When I authenticate with the **ressourceowner** i can see at the claimsprincipal that the id is set in

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
```

where is there a an offset? Is this an indication that I misscoded something? or is this an expected behavior and if yes, why?

-- Update

Configuration in the api

```
 app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = identServer
            });
```

External Auth config in IdentityServer

```
 var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
                Caption = "Facebook",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                AppId = "43543534543534534",
                AppSecret = "sad345345345345354"
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);
```

Client config in identityServer

```
 return new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "pluto",
                ClientName = "Pluto Site",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("foo".Sha256())
                },
                Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "read"
                }
            };
```

Comment: Sounds like a JWT handler configuration issue to me.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/

Comment: Sorry can't see the relation the linked post you write about the OpenIdConnectOptions but currently i only have the  IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions. am I missing something? I also added the config code to my initial post.

Comment: I also tried to set  NameClaimType = "subject" in the api config, but nothing changed

Comment: @leastprivilege found. not sure if its part of documentation maybe i overread it. i was just missing clearing the fefault claimtypemapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I was missing clearing default mappings..
It was part in the tutorials but never explaind why...

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```